# How to prevent ggplot2 from considering a point as an outlier

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with three columns, Membrane, Stage, and Treatment. I want to create a boxplot of Membrane according to both stage and treatment. I have used the following code to generate the boxplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=Stage, y=Membrane, colour=Stage)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  labs(title="Membrane localization under different treatments", 
       y="Membrane Intensity") +
       facet_grid(. ~ Treatment)
```

which gives me this graph:

As you can see, for the left most plot, there are many outliers at the top. I would like for the boxplot to include those outliers within it -- ie I would like ggplot2 to consider those points normal points, and not outliers.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to extend the range of the normal boxplot whiskers, you can change the `coef` parameter. In geom_boxplot's documentation, it's defined as:

> length of the whiskers as multiple of IQR. Defaults to 1.5

Changing it to `coef = <some number larger than 1.5>` will extend the whiskers & remove the corresponding outliers. For example:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Stage, y=Membrane, colour=Stage)) + 
  geom_boxplot(coef = 5) + 
  labs(title="Membrane localization under different treatments", 
       y="Membrane Intensity") +
       facet_grid(. ~ Treatment)
```

Note, if this is what you want, it's best that you annotate your plot so that your audience is aware of the change.

If you just want to hide the outliers, use P_Sta's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=Stage, y=Membrane, colour=Stage)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
  labs(title="Membrane localization under different treatments", 
       y="Membrane Intensity") +
       facet_grid(. ~ Treatment)
```